# usage of ...Pattern.compile()

Tags: java, regex

Using `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile()` you can specify a pattern as parameter. But how can you specify flags like case-insensitive and ignore whitespaces as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(String regex, int flags);
```

Parameters:

- `regex`, the expression to be compiled flags Match
- `flags`, a bit mask

You can set `flags` to a bitmask composed by

- `CASE_INSENSITIVE`
- `MULTILINE`
- `DOTALL`
- `UNICODE_CASE`
- `CANON_EQ`
- `UNIX_LINES`
- `LITERAL`
- `COMMENTS`

Answer (score 6):

[Use the overload that accepts flags.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 100K! (oh, and so the comment is not too chatty, you can also set flags inline: `(?si)^(.*a)` will allow the dot-all and ignore-case flags)

Comment: @Kobi Using only answers like the above. ;-) And wjans has already mentioned the inline flags, his answer needs to be upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Pattern.compile(String regex, int flags)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method that takes flags as well, or you can put them in your Pattern itself:

Eg.

```
Pattern.compile("(?i)a");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```